# How to make web app on small devices look like on desktop

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web, responsive-design

I have an web application made with Bootstrap & Angular. When I access it on my smartphone, it applies queries correctly. But some pieces of application are too big for smartphone (especially tables). And then, I had a look at strava.com on my smartphone, and for instance their page renders the same on smartphone as on big devices.

For instance, go to strava.com (and log in if you have an account) with smartphone and from PC. Application looks the same on smartphone & PC. And I don't know how to achieve it.

What technique they are using? Anyway, I was thinking about applying css zoom property to some pieces of the page (or set constant widths of body, but it did not help), but I'm not sure if this is correct way to go. Could you advice?

Comment: The question is not clear, can you show us some examples what you want to achieve. Try to look up for media queries may be that can help.

Comment: For tables I tend to use the bootstrap table-responsive class. Once it reaches it's limit it'll add a horizontal scroll keeping the table looking correct and hiding the overflow that would be there without it.

If I want it to be truly responsive and have no scroll, I tend to style other elements to make them look like a table and then just handle how they appear on smaller viewports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you are not coding a responsive site, just don’t use any meta viewport.

Some description can be found here:

- http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972
- http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho